# How to Incorporate External Design Elements in a WordPress Site

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have lots of fantastic PSD, CSS and HTML design resources from places like CodeCanyon, CoDrops, multiple designer bundles, etc.  I'd like to incorporate some of them into a WordPress site, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do it and I've looked everywhere I can think of, from CSS-Tricks.com and the Codex to For-Dummies books :)

I'm familiar with HTML, basic CSS and WordPress, but I'm (obviously) not a designer. I do know how to call an external stylesheet using @import or within  tags, but how do I pull in the rest of the files?

For instance, I have an item called CSS3Accordion and it contains several index.html files as well as folders containing css, images and javascript.  How should I reference them in my theme and where should I put them?

I'm assuming this is a very elementary question (so much so that these awesome design resources don't typically come with a how-to file), so in advance, let me say I sincerely appreciate any help I might get.

Comment: It's not elementary, you will need to know PHP, Javascript and HTML/CSS. There is no magic button.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a WP template to a WP site and coding one are two very different things. Those resources you are using, are they WP themes? If so, you should be able to install them quite easily using the control panel. If not, it's a completely new horizon. Templates don't function like "normal" html + css, they need much more things (specially, they need to be read by WP and its modules, widgets, etcetera).

I would suggest you start by downloading and installing themes (plenty of tutorials around), and then modifying some of those themes. They usually come with a custom css sheet to add/change styles (use firebug to find them, use !important to overwrite).

I hope this answers your question. If it's only a matter of loading new css, you can still add all of it to the custom sheet. There are also a lot of free plugins (like the accordion) that you can install in WP. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with a basic wordPress theme and incorporate your ideas as you go with some trial and error. WordPress themes are actually pretty straight forward once you spend some time dissecting a basic one. Most of the time I start with a complete design in Photoshop and use that image as a background to layout the sliced graphics over with CSS.

You can place your files anywhere you want, but I normally put them inside the themes folder and reference them with relative file paths, remember though to take the path into account when linking to the files.

I'd also suggest setting up a locally hosted WordPress install to play around with using something like WAMP, MAMP or LAMP. That way you have instant review without having to expose it to the public or uploading files every time you make a change.

Here are a couple of good starting template themes to explore with.

http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/

http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-naked/

Regards and good luck.

Comment: Thanks to you and @yisela, but I think I've miscommunicated my familiarity with WordPress. I've been running self-hosted sites for years and coding child themes for quite awhile. In that time, however, I've managed to avoid PhotoShop, so what I mean by "resources" are files that others have created, that I'd like to reference in a child theme. So in my child theme's style.css, I reference the stylesheet for say, a custom slider element that I've uploaded into its directory, create a class for the element and reference the class within the HTML of a theme file. I'm missing a step though...